# Get an email's SentOn date given its subject and a specified date range to copy into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to search a number of email titles given in a spreadsheet between a range specified in VBA. Then, I need to paste the SentOn time into Excel using a two way lookup.

I am able to do this for the current date only, as when I input a date before the current date, the two way lookup pastes the SentOn date for today's email. This makes me think that I have messed up searching Outlook. Here is the (truncated) code I am using:

```
Dim filterStr As String
filterStr = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & EmailName & "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date >= '" & TDateUTC & "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date <= '" & TDateUTCEOD & "' "

For Each OutputType In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Static Data").Range("F:F")
    If OutputType.value = "Email" Then
        ProcessName = OutputType.Offset(0, -5).value
        EmailName = OutputType.Offset(0, 2).value

    On Error Resume Next
        If Not (TargetInbox.Items.AdvancedSearch(TargetInbox, filterStr, False, "criteria") Is Nothing) Then

        SLA_Completion_Tracker_FileName.Activate
        MatchFormula1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate(TDate)), ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)
        MatchFormula2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(ProcessName, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), 0)

        EmailTime = TargetInbox.Items.Item(EmailName).SentOn
        If Not EmailTime >= TDate And EmailTime <= TDateEOD Then EmailTime = ""

        SLA_Completion_Tracker_FileName.Activate
        Set IndexFormula = WorksheetFunction.Index(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FA60"), MatchFormula2, MatchFormula1)

        IndexFormula.value = Format(EmailTime, "ddddd ttttt")

End If
```

This is currently working for today's date. 
However, when I set it up to search for a previous date, I replace this:

```
EmailTime = TargetInbox.Items.Item(EmailName).SentOn
If Not EmailTime >= TDate And EmailTime <= TDateEOD Then EmailTime = ""
```

With this:

```
EmailTime = TargetInbox.Items.AdvancedSearch(TargetInbox, filterStr, False, "criteria").Item(EmailName).SentOn
```

Nothing shows up. I realize this is because I am not using the AdvancedSearch function properly, so can someone help me out here? How do I use it properly for this task?

Thanks

EDIT: I have been trying Find as well, using this code:

```
EmailName = OutputType.Offset(0, 2).value
Dim sFilter As String
sFilter = "[Subject] = """ & EmailName & """ AND [SentOn] >= '" & Format(TDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND [SentOn] <= '" & Format(TDateEOD, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
FoundMail = TargetInbox.Items.Find(sFilter)
FoundTime = FoundMail.SentOn
```

But this hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, figured out my problem.

Here's what I ended up doing, in case anyone stumbles upon this:

```
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim ProcessName As String
Dim EmailName As String

Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders('your value here)
Set TargetInbox = objFolder.Folders('your value here)

Dim oItms As Outlook.Items
Dim oItm As Outlook.MailItem
Set oItms = TargetInbox.Items
Dim sFilter As String
Dim EmailTime As String

    sFilter = "[Subject] = """ & EmailName & """ AND [SentOn] >= '" & Format(TDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND [SentOn] <= '" & Format(TDateEOD, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
    Set oItm = oItms.Find(sFilter)
    EmailTime = oItm.SentOn
```

Turned out to be pretty simple in the end.

Answer (score 0):

`AdvancedSearch` is asynchronous and you need to wait for it to finish.
Why not just use `MAPIFolder.Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`?

Comment: I have been trying that but I can't seem to make Find work either. I have edited the Find I am testing in my OP.